# Passing an HTML parameter in routes (Play framework)

Tags: html, playframework, routes

Good day! How are HTML parameters expressed in the `routes` file? I am trying to pass an HTML but I don't know how. All I know are passing integers (`(id: Integer)`) and some data types. I tried `(content: Html)`and `(content: Html)`. I also tried `javax.swing.text.html.HTML` but it says something about `QueryStringBindable`. Please help me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that all you pass by route's params will be included in the URL so what is the advantage of using HTML in this place ? GET params should use only simple data types like numerical types, booleans and strings - so you can pass some HTML part as a String (preferably url-encoded or even beter with [Base64 encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)).

Much better option is sending it via POST, your URLs won't be terrible long - you won't hit any limitation of URL length, also after common serialization it won't break at special HTML chars.